# Dynamic Column Names in JQuery DataTables

Tags: jquery, ajax, json, datatables

Im not able to declare the table headers dynamically in the datatables. Here's what i've tried so far:

```
if (result != "[]") {

        var resultColumns = [];

        $.each(result.Columns, function(i, value){

            var obj = { sTitle: value };

            resultColumns.push(obj);
        });


        $('#trendingTable').dataTable({
            "aaData": result,
            //important  -- headers of the json
            "aoColumns": [ resultColumns ],
            "sPaginationType": "full_numbers",
            "aaSorting": [[0, "asc"]],
            "bJQueryUI": true,
            "bDestroy": true,

        });
    }
```

My JSON result:

```
{"Column1":["ABC","XYZ"],"Column2":[0.0,0.0],"Colum3":[0.0,0.0],,"Columns":["Column1","Column2","Colum3"]}
```

Answer (score 4, accepted):

You have two options to achieve this.

**1**. Change your JSON result to below format:

`{"COLUMNS":[{ sTitle: "COLUMN1"},
   { sTitle: "COLUMN2"}, { sTitle: "COLUMN3"}],
    "DATA":[[" ABC","DEF","XYZ"],["0.0,"0.0","0.0"],["1","2","3"],["I","II","III"]]}`

**2.** As jQuery Datatable is HTML table that render rows and columns, parse your JSON result
   and append columns to `table thead`.